# How do I implement the Decorator pattern when using many decorators

Tags: design-patterns

I'm programming a coffee machine with many kinds of coffee. I offer normal coffee, espresso, cappuccino, but also Irish coffee (whiskey, coffee, sugar, whipped cream), Spanish Coffee (Cointreau, cognac, coffee, sugar, whipped cream) and Italian Coffee (Amaretto, coffee, sugar, whipped cream).

I'm planning to add more kinds of coffee in the future, that's why it needs to be easy to add more coffees without adding a class for each kind.

My solution would be to use the decorator pattern. However this will leave me with so many decorators like `SugarDecorator`, `MilkDecorator`, `WhiskeyDecorator`, `AmarettoDecorator`, `WhippedCreamDecorator` ...

How can I fix this without adding a decorator for each condiment?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477241/decorator-pattern-mess

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768349/builder-vs-decorator-pattern) to add more attributes to Coffee, e.g. add sugar and milk:

```
Coffee.builder().sugar(true).milk(true).build();
```

This way there's no extra classes, only attributes, but you need to *build* it on coffee creation

> Builder Pattern makes it easy to construct an object which is extensible in independent directions at construction time, while the Decorator Pattern lets you add extensions to functionality to an object after construction time

Comment: How do I implement this in c# without creating classes?

Comment: @Frogicall see examples, as https://exceptionnotfound.net/builder-pattern-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case for *Decorator*, looks like you wish to add optional ingredients. For this purpose you can use *Builder* as suggested by @user7294900.

Decorator pattern can be used when we wish to *add a new functionality* to an object while using earlier object as a raw material. In general why we need to be worried about added decorator classes (when required), as long as they provide required add-on functionality to existing object. Decorator classes do not add extra cost as they are optionally added at run time and are of *pay-as-you-use type*.