# Can you create a FileWriter or BufferedWriter directly from an InputStream?

Tags: java, file-io

So I am using Java.net.URL to get a connection to a URL that contains some xml (.atom?) data for parsing for writing to a local file.

This is teaching me a lot about reading and writing. Here is my current process:

1. create URL object
2. get a "Stream"
3. Create a InputStreamReader
4. Wrap the ISR in Buffered Reader
5. Create FileWriter
6. Wrap FW in Bufferedwriter
7. line by line, read then write
8. close the BufferedWriter.

It works! I learned the difference between reader, BufferedReader, writer and BfferedWriter. That's great. I'm a little unclear on streams, but that's ok for now.

**However, I was wondering if there is a way to create a BufferedWriter directly from an InputStream to save all those middle steps.**

1. Create URL object
2. get a "Stream"
3. skip straight to BufferedWriter()
4. write to local file.
5. close the BufferedWriter

I see the BufferedWriter constuctor takes a writer, so I'm assuming not, but I can't help but wonder if you could cut down some steps.

Comment: You seem to only be concerned with downloading data into a local file. If that's the case then you don't need to use a `Reader` or a `Writer`, as you're not trying to decode the binary data into characters or vice versa. Transferring the data (i.e. the raw bytes) from the `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` is sufficient (though you may want to use buffers/buffered-streams). Is there more to your application that requires using a reader and/or a writer?

Comment: @Slaw Yeah, that's the heart of my question. I just want to save data from the URL straight to file. I don't need to do any intermediate manipulations with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you create a FileWriter or BufferedWriter directly from an InputStream?

No. As you've noted, `BufferedWriter` wraps another instance of `Writer`. This is Java's [quintessential example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068912/what-is-the-most-used-pattern-in-java-io) of the [Decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) pattern.

One of the [cons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486676/1371329) of the Decorator pattern is that it tends to produce a lot of little objects that need to be composed.

On the bright side, in addition to teaching you a lot about reading and writing, this exercise has now taught you about design patterns as well!

Comment: Thanks, that's good stuff to know. This, plus another answer shows me that I can just use an input and output stream to write the raw data without the readers and writers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = URI.create("https://www.example.com/").toURL().openStream()) {
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"))) {
                int read;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the byte[] list should be initiated to 1024, out of curiosity?

Comment: You can choose a different chunk size to read in one go. It depends on your requirement which is driven by factors like, memory, bandwidth etc.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question: No, you cannot go directly from an `InputStream` / `OutputStream` to a `BufferedReader` / `BufferedWriter`. The problem is you need a class which can translate from an input/output stream, which deals directly with bytes, to a reader/writer, which deals with characters (i.e. by decoding bytes into characters and vice versa). As pointed out by [@jaco0646's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60141470/6395627), this is one of the cons of the decorator pattern. Of course, you could make a utility method:

```java
public static BufferedReader toBufferedReader(InputStream stream, Charset charset) {
  return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, charset));
}
```

To make your other code shorter. Though I'm sure there's already a library out there that provides this (e.g. maybe [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) or [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)).

That all being said, you don't appear to need a reader or a writer. Your question indicates, and you later confirm in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140203/can-you-create-a-filewriter-or-bufferedwriter-directly-from-an-inputstream#comment106374217_60140203), that you're simply downloading data directly into a file. This means you have no need to decode the bytes into characters only to immediately encode the characters back into bytes. You just need to transfer the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` directly. Here's some examples (staying within the JDK):

#### Manually copying the bytes using a buffer

```java
public static void copyUrlToFile(URL url, File file) throws IOException {
  try (InputStream input = url.openStream();
      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8]; // 8 KiB buffer
    int read;
    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
  }
}
```

Could also use [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [`Files#newOutputStream(Path,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) instead of `File` and `FileOutputStream`.

#### Using [`InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) (Java 9+)

```java
public static void copyUrlToFile(URL url, File file) throws IOException {
  try (InputStream input = url.openStream();
      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    input.transferTo(output);
  }
}
```

#### Using [`Files#copy(InputStream,Path,CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

```java
public static void copyUrlToFile(URL url, Path file) throws IOException {
  try (InputStream input = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
  }
}
```

---

Note that, when using NIO, you can open buffered readers and writers to files directly using [`Files#newBufferedReader(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)) and [`Files#newBufferedWriter(Path,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)), respectively.